# What does nonReentrant modifier do for multiple transactions in one block

Tags: blockchain, solidity, openzeppelin

If `nonReentrant` modifier is used for transfer function, or mint function, and during periods of high volume of transactions if multiple transactions get submitted in one block, then what does `nonReentrant` do to subsequent transactions in the same block? Will it revert them? How does `nonReentrant` behave for simultaneous transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are always executed in series, even in the same block.

The single-underscore line (`_;`) in the `nonReentrant` modifier ([code](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.7.3/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol#L50-L62)) divides blocks of code that are executed before the function, and after the function.

Each transaction executing a function that uses this modifier validates that the `_status` is `_NOT_ENTERED` (otherwise throws an exception), sets it as `_ENTERED`, then executes the function, and then sets the `_status` back to `_NOT_ENTERED`.

If the transaction throws an uncaught exception, the contract is reverted back to the state before this transaction. In this case, `_status` is reverted back to `_NOT_ENTERED`.

In both cases, when another transaction comes in, the value of `_status` is always `_NOT_ENTERED`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception about [reentrancy](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/reentrancy-after-istanbul/).

Reentrancy happens when a smart contract function calls out to another contract which then calls the original contract ("re-entering"), all within one transaction.

The point of the OpenZeppelin `nonReentrant` modifier is to protect a smart contract function from reentrancy, which by definition always happens in the same transaction.  It's not meant to block a function from ever being used again in other transactions (regardless of whether they are in the same block or not).